# Disable name prefix in javadoc

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javadoc

When generating the Javadoc, it adds on prefix to the imported class name, as shown below on the first line 'java.lang'.

How to properly disable that?

Have tried adding -noqualifier in Other command line arguments in my IntelliJ popup window but the following error occurred:

javadoc: error - Illegal package name: "/Users"

Below is a snippet from the Javadoc I generated:

```
public TrainRoute(java.lang.String name,
                  int routeNumber)
Creates a new TrainRoute with the given name and number.
Should meet the specification of Route.Route(String, int)

Parameters:
name - The name of the route.
routeNumber - The route number of the route.
```

Comment: How are you running Javadoc?

Comment: IntellJ -> Tools -> Generate Javadoc

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but still relevant. I am aware of two solution which can be used alone or in combination:

To suppress prefixes on java packages use:

```
-noqualifier java.*
```

To suppress prefixes and link to the actual Java docs use:

```
-link https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api
```

Both suppress the java name qualifiers. The second also links to the Oracle docs.

See [javadoc options docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#javadocoptions) for more info.

Comment: -link was just what I needed - thanks @dschultz